# Allow Remote Connections to MySql Database

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, database, remote-access

I have looked at this [Post](https://serverfault.com/questions/288812/allow-connections-from-a-remote-server-in-mysql) and it details how you can allow a connection from a remote host to the database. But the line that took me off guard was this:

`mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO user@50.xx.xx.xx IDENTIFIED BY "pass";`.

It looks like you have to grant permissions to each remote client that wants to access the database?

What if I want to allow all remote clients to be able to access the database? How can this be done instead of having to identify each one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using wildcards for the host part.

```
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user@50.xx.xx.%' IDENTIFIED BY "pass";
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user@%' IDENTIFIED BY "pass";
```

Be careful though, this is dangerous.

Comment: Thanks! This might be a dumb question, but what is the `"pass"` part of the statement do? Is this my password for root?

Comment: Also, does using `user@%` allow for all users? It doesnt need to be `roo@%` or anything, right?

Comment: The `pass` option is the password for the user `user` coming from this specified host.  This can be different depending on from where you connect. And no, `user@%` is valid only for the user `user`, but coming from everywhere. MySQL explicitly disallow wildcards for users, so the form `%@%` is not possible.