# How do i enable outside connections to mysql server?

Tags: mysql

I want to use navicat to connect to mysql.  How do I set that up on my server?  It's centos

Comment: Is this your own server or VPS, or a shared host? If it is your's then don't open mySQL directly to the public Internet, instead use SSH tunneling or a VPN. If it is a shared host then there is nothing you can do other than consider server-side solutions like phpMyAdmin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow Remote Connections to MySql Database](http://serverfault.com/questions/318406/allow-remote-connections-to-mysql-database)

Comment: dedicated server

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what your config file (/etc/my.cnf or /etc/mysql/my.cnf) has in it.

If there is the line "skip-networking" then remove it, since that means MySQLD is not even listening for TCP connections.

The bind-address=... option can also be disabling external connections if it is set to an internal address (127.0.0.1 or localhost for instance). If you want to allow connections from anywhere, comment out (or remove) the bind-address=... line completely (as well as the skip-networking line).

Oh yeah, and don't forget to restart the MySQLD service after you save the file.

Answer (score 1):

As [documented](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_bind-address), under [mysqld] in your my.cnf file:

```
bind-address=an.ip.add.ress
```

lets you specify one IP to bind to, or none (comment it out); there are no other options, i.e. you cannot specify two IPs.

Answer (score 0):

in the /etc/mysql/my.cnf file edit the line that starts with bind

Comment: the mysql folder is in /usr/bin/mysql  and the folder is green and says it's not a directory